# how to define custom Map type in typescript?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to define a Map type using Typescript generics. what I want is something like this

```
EntityMap<U, V>, U can be only string or number
```

this is what I have done so far

```
export type EntityMapKey = string | number;
export type EntityMap<U, V> = { [K in EntityMapKey]: V};
```

but when we use it we can put anything as U like below

```
interface Jobs {
  list: EntityMap<Array, JobFile>
}
```

I want to restrict using any type other than **string** or **number** as U, how can we achieve this?

am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

U in your EntityMap is not used, the correct implementation should be

```
export type EntityMapKey = string | number;
export type EntityMap<U extends EntityMapKey, V> = { [K in U]: V};
interface Jobs {
  list: EntityMap<string, any>
}
```

Comment: But still, we can use any type for U ex: EntityMap<Array, any> still valid

Comment: `any ` can be used anywhere regardless of the type guard, this is by design